# Mark points on a pseudocolor plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm given a matrix C and I use `pcolor` command in order to create a surface.

Also I'm given a vector

```
Z_k=[1 0.30902+0.95106*1i 0.30902-0.95106*1i -0.80902+0.588779*1i -0.80902-0.58779*1i];
```

and I want to mark these points (in Z_k) on the pcolor(C).

I know the process is:

```
 pcolor(C)   
 hold on   
 plot(Z_k,'*')
 hold off
```

However, my marks appear on a different diagram and they don't appear at all.

What can I do?

Comment: Your given vector Zk has complex values in it. Is this intended?

Comment: Z_k is as given above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed course of action is correct. Something else must be wrong.

Example:

```
pcolor(magic(3));
hold on;
plot([1+1i, 2+2i, 3+3i], '*');
```

Marks points on a color surface.

Comment: is it okay to write plot(Z_k,'o') or putting Z_k into the plot may cause the problem? Shall I put the points specifically?

Comment: @user189013 that should not make a difference, I extended my example to also use complex numbers and it still works, so you have a specific problem with your special Zk number or your custom matrix C